# Deterministic algorithm with math

Tags: simple-functions

Well, I’m not too good with math and I don’t know all of the special symbols, but I have one (maybe) simple goal to achieve:
How do I create a deterministic algorithm in math?

Well, the only input that it’s ever going to recieve is 1,2, and 3, so that might make it eaisier.

But, the problem is that I want it to trick the person who’s doing it so that they don’t know that it’s always going to output the same number.

I know that ciel(x/3) works but like I said, I want it to trick the person.

Comment: So you don't know what an algorithm is, but you do want to find an algorithm that tricks people.Are you connected in any way with the outgoing president of the USA?

Comment: @RobArthan I am not connected! I know what an algorithm is, but it’s just that I’ve been doing code so I’m more used to coding and not math. LOL

Comment: I should gave qualified my comment: $\ddot{\smile}$.